# longurl error when expanding urls

Tags: r, url, expand

I have a list of tinyurls which I am converting to their original urls using the longurl package and expand_urls function.

When I run the code I get the error message "ERROR : subscript out of bounds"
This is due to some of the input urls being incorrect due to unwanted text (e.g.  "t.co/zTlxsyMET5 XYZA")

How do I make the code skip past an erroneous row/tinyurl and go to the next one (i.e. not stop)?

```
 example of data in dataframe called instagram_link_check, column name 
 "text":

t.co/zTlxsyMET5
t.co/zT25mYs4qe
t.co/ZSwk1rAtve

tinyurls <- as.character(instagram_link_check$text)
big_urls <- tryCatch({expand_urls(tinyurls)}, error=function(e){cat("ERROR 
:",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
```

Comment: Your code appears to be working fine.  It returns the error message as expected, but if I look at `View(big_urls)` every url that is correct is expanded out. I used `tinyurls <- c("t.co/zTlxsyMET5  XYZ", "t.co/zTlxsyMET5", "t.co/zTlxsyMET5")` to test.

Comment: it's good that those are working! though my issue is that other examples exist which aren't solely a tinyurl (could you use the erronoues data example as above) t.co/zTlxsyMET5 XYZA

Comment: I think the first entry in my vector is an equivalent example, is it not? `"t.co/zTlxsyMET5 XYZ"`

Comment: Ah so it is, my mistake!

Comment: The code isn't populating the big_urls object for me, not sure why the issue isn't replicating with the above snippet

Comment: can you provide a `dput()` of `instagram_link_check$text`?